# Rails find permalink error on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im try use Edit a Product in my App, but when i click to edit im go to this url:

http://0.0.:3000/admin/products/1/edit

Ok, its alright my route is

```
  resources :products

  namespace :admin do  
    resources :products  
  end
```

But when i click in update this error appear:

```
Couldn't find Product with id=capa-para-iphone-4-silicone
```

im understood the error but i dont know because what find by permalink when i put in my controller this in edit and update:

```
@product = Product.find(params[:id])
```

Im using gem has_permalink but i put this gem some in show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in the controller's update method:

```
@product = Product.find_by_permalink(params[:id])
```